# Edit a column of strings in whitespace delimited data using command substitution and Bash utilities

Tags: bash, awk, multiple-columns, edit

I want to apply a change to each string of one column in whitespace delimited data using the program basename (or some other program). Specifically, I have data in a form such as the following:

```
string string string /afs/address/user/directory1 string string string string
```

I want to change the data (the strings in the fourth column) so that it appears as follows:

```
string string string directory1 string string string string
```

This may be achieved using a program such as basename on each line of the fourth column. The solution I would like would incorporate some sort of command substitution such that I could use some program other than basename in editing each line of the column. So, something such as the following possibly may appear in the solution:

```
"$(basename $4)",
```

where $4 represents a line in column 4. I think I know how I would cycle over every line explicitly using inefficient code, but I imagine there is an efficient approach using something like awk that would be more elegant. Would you have any suggestions for how to approach this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
awk '{sub(/.*\//,"",$4)}1' file
```

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. Forgive me if I'm doing something silly (I'm unfamiliar with awk), but I'm having some difficulty with this. When I execute the command, I am presented with a syntax error indicated at the second, closing chain bracket. Is there something obvious that I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Sorry, it was missing the closing ")" for the sub() command. I've fixed it now.

Comment: if/when you've selected an answer you're happy with you should click on the check mark next to it so others know you got your answer.

Answer (score 1):

ED's solution should work for you.

in case you love to use `basename` :

```
awk '{"basename "$4|getline $4}1' file
```

Comment: Just be aware that if you do that then you'll be exposed to globbing, word splitting, file name expansion, etc. so it may fail in highly cryptic ways and even if it returns, what you get back may not look much like the $4 you started with.

Comment: Thanks for your help on this. Forgive me if I'm doing something silly (I'm unfamiliar with awk), but I'm having some difficulty with this. When I execute the command, I am presented with the error "sh: /afs/address/user/directory1: No such file or directory". Would you happen to know what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

If none of the other columns contains a slash, you can use <kbd>/</kbd> as the field separator and print the first and last fields:

```
awk -F / '{print $1 $NF}' <<< "string string string /afs/address/user/directory1 string string string string"
```

outputs

```
string string string directory1 string string string string
```